# Freeze activity/method execution until get a response from an dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to implement an administration mode when the user tap 7 times on back button.
Then, A dialog message will be called with editText asking for a password. if the password matches with the one in the database, I set `passwordMacthes` as TRUE and return it to whatever calls the dialog `setTapCount` and to start administration mode activity.

However, `return passordMatches` always return FALSE because it finishes the execution before  the dialogMessage verifies the password and be dismissed or canceled by the user.

here is my `setTapCount` method :

```
    public static boolean setTapCount(Context context){
        tapCount = tapCount + 1;
        if(tapCount == 7){
            tapCount = 0;
            dialogMessage(context);
            return passwordMatches;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
     }
```

Does anyone know how to call the line below of `dialogMessage(context)` only once it is finished ?

thanks

Comment: I suggest you to use callback, lock does not looks like a good solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Move that line to the handler for the accept button in the dialog, and rewrite your app to be event-driven (e.g., have `setTapCount()` accept a result listener object that can be notified of what the user did, rather than return a `boolean`).